# ionic 4 custom component animation / transition animation

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, ionic4

I have been googling this for quite some time now but haven't been able to find an answer that I can use.

I am trying to make a top-down transition for one of my pages. So I started looking into how to make a custom animation with ionic. Most of the guides tell me to use: `@angular/animations` however whenever I attempt to import it I get an error that it can't find the module.

Also, most of the guides online are how to animate a modal or alert box but never how to apply this to a navigation transition.

So how can i make a custom top-down transition when navigating in `ionic 4?`